# Strange symbol in vim command line after start

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminfo, konsole

I'm using Kubuntu 15.10, konsole and vim. When I initially start vim in konsole, i get strange symbols ("115;0c") in my command line, which is really annoying.

i tried "set term=konsole" setting in my .vimrc but i got this

```
E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'konsole' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_gui
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'
```

but all of these options were annoying, because i got "trace" after closing quiting vim.

Does anyone have the same problem? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like your terminfo setup is hosed -- maybe reinstall the `ncurses-base` package (which should be a prereq of vim)

Comment: it didn't work please help me

Answer (score 1):

That usually indicates an incorrect `TERM` environment variable setting -- when `vim` starts up, it generates a number of terminal configuration commands base on the `TERM` setting to configure the terminal.  If the `TERM` setting is wrong, it may generate an incorrect setting string that gets displayed like this.

For a konsole window, `TERM` should be set to `konsole`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that konsole was pretending to be xterm, and confused vim.  That "115;0c" was intended (by konsole's developer) to look like the response to xterm's [secondary device response](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-gt-Ps-c.1DAB).  In particular, konsole was pretending to be xterm [patch #115](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_115), by sending this response:

> <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>`[`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`;`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd><kbd>`;`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`c`</kbd>

[konsole](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bug_konsole), like all of the xterm-wannbes, differs from xterm in ways that affect any application using terminfo (this is of course an [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions)).

The actual code:

```c
void Vt102Emulation::reportSecondaryAttributes()
{   
    // Secondary device attribute response (Request was: ^[[>0c or ^[[>c)
    if (getMode(MODE_Ansi)) {
        sendString("\033[>1;115;0c"); // Why 115?  ;)
    } else {
        sendString("\033/Z"); // FIXME I don't think VT52 knows about it but kept for
    }
    // konsoles backward compatibility.
}
```

dates back to this commit:

```
commit 2d93fed82aa27e89c9d7301d09d2e24e4fa4416d
Author: Waldo Bastian <bastian@kde.org>
Date:   Sat Sep 15 21:21:44 2001 +0000

    proper impl. of primary/secondary device attributes (DA)
    Patch by Achim Bohnet <ach@mpe.mpg.de>
 
    svn path=/trunk/kdebase/konsole/; revision=114396
 
diff --git a/konsole/TEmuVt102.cpp b/konsole/TEmuVt102.cp
```

There is a "konsole" entry in the optional [ncurses-term](https://packages.debian.org/sid/ncurses-term) package (see [source](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-konsole)).  That requires a few megabytes.  The required [ncurses-base](https://packages.debian.org/sid/ncurses-base) package is much smaller:

> This package contains terminfo data files to support the most common types of terminal, including ansi, dumb, linux, rxvt, screen, sun, vt100, vt102, vt220, vt52, and xterm.

which is a little odd, because very few people have actually used ansi, sun, or vt52 within the past 20 years, except by accident or when following poor advice.

Comment: Interesting for a question posted 7 years ago, I got this code in konsole with `tmux new true`.

I'm still figuring out how to resolve this.